# Creating a nested dict out of a list with unknown length

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to get a method that gets 3 lists and turns them into a nested dict.

The first and the second list can have any amount of entries > 0.
The values list always has `len(firstlist) * len(secondlist)` entries.

For example:

```
givenlist1 = ["First", "Second"]
givenlist2 = ["A.B.D", "A.Y.Z", "A.B.E"]
Values = ["10", "2", "3", "4", "1", "3"]
```

Should return a dict like this:

```
{'First': {'A': {'B': {'D': '10', 'E': '3'}, 'Y': {'Z': '2'}}},
 'Second': {'A': {'B': {'D': '4', 'E': '3'}, 'Y': {'Z': '1'}}}}
```

I tried a lot with `.update` but I just can't get an idea how to do it with a variable amount of entries in the second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to get the required combinations of the entries in `givenlist1` and `givenlist2`, and use `zip` to associate them with the corresponding items from `values`. Then you need to `.split` the individual letter keys from the letters in the `givenlist2` items to get the nested keys, creating new dicts as necessary.

```
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

givenlist1 = ["First", "Second"]
givenlist2 = ["A.B.D", "A.Y.Z", "A.B.E"]
values = ["10", "2", "3", "4", "1", "3"]

result = {k1: {} for k1 in givenlist1}

for (k1, k2), v in zip(product(givenlist1, givenlist2), values):
    d = result[k1]
    keys = k2.split('.')
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[keys[-1]] = v

pprint(result)
```

**output**

```
{'First': {'A': {'B': {'D': '10', 'E': '3'}, 'Y': {'Z': '2'}}},
 'Second': {'A': {'B': {'D': '4', 'E': '3'}, 'Y': {'Z': '1'}}}}
```

Here's a less compact but possibly more readable way to write the inner `for` loop:

```
for k in keys[:-1]:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = {}
    d = d[k]
```